# What's the word for someone who is supposed to be your foe but isn't because they're nice?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to find the word for Nazis who helped a Jew. I'm hoping for a word that means "should be."

Comment: How about a "friendly foe"?

Comment: I want to say she got help from her friends and "should be" foes

Comment: Then I guess you mean "her friends and *would be* foes"? *would be* here is something like "should have been", but were not in this situation.

Comment: Do you think "supposed foe" would work?

Comment: *Erstwhile foe*, perhaps.  But given the sensitive subject, you have to be careful. It would not be appropriate to describe the Nazis and the Jewish people living in Europe during the Holocaust as *foes*.  There are many ways to talk about this relationship, although it's probably better to describe it in terms of "murderers" and "victims".

Comment: No, because that would mean he was expected to be a foe, but wasn't. See [*supposed*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/supposed). Unless he completely changed sides, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase you're looking for is **would-be foes**. But I think it's inaccurate to describe Jews and Nazis as "foes," because it implies that the two groups had a natural hatred for each other and engaged in some type of comparable match, such as fighting each other on the battlefield -- which wasn't the case at all.

I think the gist of what you want to say is "false Nazi" or "sympathetic Nazi," but it's a strange thing to try to convey in a single word. I think you'd be better off describing the relationship in a more precise phrase: **Nazis who sympathized with Jews** or **Nazis who wanted to help Jews**. Or even: **would-be Nazis who sympathized with Jews.**